# The cookies is not being sent with the request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, cookies, axios

I have a reactjs client and I send it a cookie using this nodejs code

```
res.cookie("token", jwtCreation, {
       maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // Set maxAge in milliseconds (24 hours)
      sameSite: 'None', // Allow cross-site requests for modern browsers
});
```

and I don't receive it at the server. Note that that react client is running on a different domain. the requests are being made by axios.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your axios request has `{ withCredentials: true }`. Also make sure that your cors has `{ Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true }` configured.

So your request should end up looking something like this:

```
axios.post("/cookie", {}, { withCredentials: true })
```

You can also configure to do this by default using `axios.defaults.withCredentials = true`